# TFS 2015 "Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment" The system cannot execute the specified program.

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, azure-devops

Iam trying to execute TFS 2015 "Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment". It throws the  "The system cannot execute the specified program" error. I have also raised question in msdn https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7ee1d5c6-413e-417f-8892-62416101d12f/tfs-2015-visual-studio-test-agent-deployment-the-system-cannot-execute-the-specified-program?forum=tfsgeneral

Answer (score 0):

According to your error log `Deploy and configuration of test agent failed. Check the logs for more details`.

To narrow down your issue, you can try to install and configure the test agent manually. Detail steps and info you can refer this link: [Install and configure test agents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/test/test-machines/install-configure-test-agents)

And here is a blog telling you continuous deployment test: [Testing in Continuous Integration and Continuous Deployment Workflows](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/05/29/testing-in-continuous-integration-and-continuous-deployment-workflows/) you can try it follow detail steps.